# How to hide continue shopping after customer selects the second product

Tags: wordpress

I need the "Continue Shopping" button to hide from the cart after the customer selects the second product.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried plugins of max quantity purchase, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this.

Copy paste below codes according to your need

Go to your file manager > wp-content/plugins/woocomerce/templates/cart/cart.php

or you can also access this file from inside wordpress dashboard by going to plugins > plugins editor > Select plugin woocommerce from top right > templates > cart > cart.php

Now codes (I have created two cases) :

1. If you want to hide continue shopping after user adds the second product of different type (I think you asked for this one..)

```
   <?php
   $_cartQty = count( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
   if ($_cartQty >= 2){
   echo "<style type=\"text/css\">
   .woocommerce-message > a.button.wc-forward {display:none !important;}
   </style>" ;
   }
   ?>
```

2. If you want to hide continue shopping if user buys two quantity of same product

```
    <?php
    $quant = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ;
    if ($quant >= 2){
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\">
    a.button.wc-forward {display:none !important;}
    </style>" ;
    }
    ?>
```

Hi, if the solution is correct please mark it correct , thanks

Comment: Thanks! I used the fist case and it take out the "continue shopping" button but also takes out the "Checkout" button that i need. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. It's fixed now, please check.